# How do you handle 404 errors sent by a container and not by application

Tags: java, spring, jboss, http-status-code-404, wildfly

Let's assume the following REST resource

```
https://api.service.com/jobs/{id}
```

My jboss/wildfly rest application will send **404** (no body data) if job data is not available. **200** and **404** are expected response codes.

The service consumer interprets this result and starts some corresponding processes that are irrelevant at this point.

Unfortunately, the consumer also gets a 404 code if the application is **not deployed**. For example, due to a deployment error. This response code is sent by jboss/wildfly container. At this point, the consumer will misinterpret the response.

So how would you handle such a one situation? I believe the container should never send such a response, as this is the job of the application.

The most obvious solution would be some body data, so that consumer can distinguish whether the 404 came from the container or the application:

```
{
   "error": "No job found for id ..."
}
```

However, this solution does not seem to me to be clean or realy "restfull".

Answer (score 1):

The better thing do is to keep your status 200 in all the cases (on your application).
The 200 here represents that your application can be reached.

For all the other errors, you can return all the other statuses (including 200).

For example - 200:

```
{
     "response" : "Ok",
     "responseCode" : 200
     "data" : {
               "jobId" : 1
      }
}
```

For example - 404:

```
{
     "response" : "Not Found",
     "responseCode" : 404
     "data" : null
}
```

Your service consumer can listen to the response (body) that is being produced by your application, and then can differentiate between any errors that are being generated by the container and your application.

This goes for all the response messages that you want to cater on your application.

I hope this was helpful for you.